# Wrong number of args when working with multimethods and meta data

Tags: clojure

I have following code using multimethod and meta-data:

```
(defrecord Card [id name value])

(defmulti make-card (fn [m] (:source (meta m))))

(defmethod make-card :random [m] (map->Card m))
(def card-info  (with-meta {:id 1} {:source :random}))
```

when I call:

```
(make-card card-info)
```

It just throws "ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/eval1299/fn--1300  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)"

On the other hand, if I call:

```
 ((fn [m] (:source (meta m))) (with-meta {:id 1} {:source :random}))
```

It works.

Someone please tell me where I got it wrong?

Comment: It works, I copied your code and did not get any erros see: https://repl.it/JD34/1

Comment: I tried again in a separate Repl and it seems to be working now. But my Emacs and Visual Studio code (which connect to there own nRepl) just show errors. Seems like a tool integration problem. Thank you!

Comment: It works also for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because I need to close this question, hence I need to answer my own question (no other one did). Actually I think this is the problem of cider or something on Windows. I don't know if it's different on Linux or MacOS. I am using Windows and somehow the nRepl which connects to Emacs and Visual Studio code just mess up. If I try to run a separate repl, it works fine.

Comment: Had the same problem and came accross  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/XcsouTQeLxw   which says "If you change multimethod arities you'll have to def the multimethod to nil or restart the [repl]. It doesn't update that on recompilation."